# remove blank lines when uploading csv files angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, csv, filereader

I got a  csv-reader directive and let's user upload a csv file. I noticed that when I upload a file with spaces between words  for example:
abc
abc
abc

abc

abc

this gets shown. I want to delete all the blank lines Not sure what to do.
[image]

```
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    var rows = contents.split('\n');                

                    // Check if the last row is empty. This works
                    if(rows[rows.length-1] ===''){
                        rows.pop()
}
}


     // this doesn't work for some reason. It doesn't detect the '' in the middle of the arrays.

    for( var i=rows.length-1;i>0;i--){
      if(rows[i] === ''){
        rows.splice(i,1)
      }
    }
```

Comment: you probably have a \r char in there as well (line is not empty).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Array.prototype.filter()`

```
var rows = contents.split('\n').filter(function(str){
    return str;
});
```

Comment: still returning the array with empty strings inside... If I do rows[3]==='', it gives false but if i do rows[rows.length-1]==='', it returns true

Comment: Create demo in plunker that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0):

From what you have shown it looks like you want to check if each item in the `csvModel` is an empty string, rather than `newValue`

Something like:

```
for( var i=0 ;i< $scope.csvModel.length; i++){    
    if (csvModel[i] == "") {
        $scope.csvModel.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't splice in middle of forward looking loop. Throws indexing off on future iterations. Can do it when looping in reverse though

Comment: for( var i=array.length-1;i>0 ; i--){
                            if([i] === ""){
                                array.splice(i,1)
                            }
                            
                        }

Comment: @charlietfl go reverse like that? it's still not removing the ""

Comment: @Angular most likely it's not equal to `""` due to line breaks. Really depends how you are generating `$scope.csvModel`. Not enough shown for us to know

Comment: what if it's just a simple array, ["abc", "abc", "", "abc"]

Comment: @Angular judging by your ng-repeat looks like you have array of objects no?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = [];
var target = $event.target || $event.srcElement;
var files = target.files;

if(Constants.validateHeaderAndRecordLengthFlag){
  if(!this._fileUtil.isCSVFile(files[0])){
    alert("Please import valid .csv file.");
    this.fileReset();
  }
}

var input = $event.target;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(input.files[0], 'UTF-8');

reader.onload = (data) => {
  let csvData = reader.result;
  let csvRecordsArray = csvData.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  if (csvRecordsArray[csvRecordsArray.length - 1] === '') {
    csvRecordsArray.pop();
  }
  var headerLength = -1;
  if(Constants.isHeaderPresentFlag){
    let headersRow = this._fileUtil.getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArray, Constants.tokenDelimeter);
    headerLength = headersRow.length;
  }

  this.csvRecords = this._fileUtil.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray,
    headerLength, Constants.validateHeaderAndRecordLengthFlag, Constants.tokenDelimeter);
  if(this.csvRecords===null){
    this.csvRecords=[];
  }
  else if(this.csvRecords!==null) {
    if ((JSON.stringify(this.csvRecords[0])) === (JSON.stringify(this.csvFormate))) {
      alert("format matches");
      this.displayCsvContent = true;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.csvRecords.length; i++) {
        if (i !== 0) {
          this.csvRecords[i].push(this.recordInsertedFlag);
        }
      }

    }
    else {
      alert("format not matches");

    }
  }

  if(this.csvRecords == null){
    this.displayCsvContent=false;
    //If control reached here it means csv file contains error, reset file.
    this.fileReset();
  }
};

reader.onerror = function () {
  alert('Unable to read ' + input.files[0]);

};
```